# cannot resolve column due to data type mismatch PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

Error being faced in PySpark:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`result_set`.`dates`.`trackers`['token']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''token'' is of string type.;;\n'Project [result_parameters#517, result_set#518, <lambda>(result_set#518.dates.trackers[token]) AS result_set.dates.trackers.token#705]\n+- Relation[result_parameters#517,result_set#518] json\n"
```

Data strucutre:

```
-- result_set: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- trackers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- countries: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- os_names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- kpi_values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- os_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- token: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- token: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to create a view to show currency, date, and token:

```
df.select('result_set.currency', 'result_set.dates.date', 'result_set.dates.trackers.token').show()
```

Sample of data:

```
"result_set": {
        "token": "abcdef",
        "name": "Facebook",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "dates": [
            {
                "date": "2020-03-11",
                "trackers": [
                    {
                        "token": "12345",
                        "countries": [
                            {
                                "country": "am",
                                "os_names": [
                                    {
                                        "os_name": "android",
                                        "kpi_values": [
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            1,
                                            0,
                                            0
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
```

I am trying to create a view based on a few of these levels within the json data.

Update:

Duplicating token

```
df.selectExpr('result_set.currency','explode(result_set.dates)').\
select("*","col.*").\
selectExpr("explode(trackers)","*").\
selectExpr("currency","date","explode(trackers)").\
select("currency","date","col.*").\
selectExpr("currency","date","token", "explode(countries)").\
select("currency","date","token", "col.*").\
selectExpr("currency","date","token", "country", "explode(os_names)").\
select("currency","date","token", "country", "col.*").\
selectExpr("currency","date","token", "country", "os_name", "explode(kpi_values)").\
show(20)
```

After doing some explodes, now the token repeats 8 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are accessing **`array of structs`** we need to give which element from **array** we need to access i.e `0,1,2..`etc.

- if we need to select all elements of array then we need to use **`explode()`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- result_set: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- dates: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- trackers: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |-- countries: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- os_names: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- kpi_values: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- os_name: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |-- token: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- token: string (nullable = true)

#accessing token,date from array
df.selectExpr('result_set.dates.trackers[0].token','result_set.currency', 'result_set.dates.date').show()
#+--------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+
#|result_set.dates.trackers AS trackers#194[0].token|currency|        date|
#+--------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+
#|                                           [12345]|     EUR|[2020-03-11]|
#+--------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+

#accessing first elements from dates, trackers array and extracting date,token values
df.selectExpr('result_set.dates[0].trackers[0].token as token','result_set.currency', 'result_set.dates[0].date as date').show()
#+-----+--------+----------+
#|token|currency|      date|
#+-----+--------+----------+
#|12345|     EUR|2020-03-11|
#+-----+--------+----------+

#if you need to select all elements of array then we need to explode the array and select the data
df.selectExpr('result_set.currency','explode(result_set.dates)').\
select("*","col.*").\
selectExpr("explode(trackers)","*").\
selectExpr("currency","date","explode(trackers)").\
select("currency","date","col.*").\
select("currency","date","token").\
show()

#+--------+----------+-----+
#|currency|      date|token|
#+--------+----------+-----+
#|     EUR|2020-03-11|12345|
#+--------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: @dataviews, Try this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/sql/index.html documented all the spark functions!

Comment: how could i access all of the nested arrays? is there a way to use a loop for the arrays that I'm indexing? @Shu

Comment: @dataviews, in built spark doesn't have that function yet!, refer to these links for dynamic flattening... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471346/automatically-and-elegantly-flatten-dataframe-in-spark-sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271398/flatten-nested-spark-dataframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178325/flatten-nested-struct-in-pyspark-array

Comment: this is one of the data structures I'm trying to unpack:
[[[zz, [[[1347.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0E-4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], android]]]],

Comment: @dataviews, if it is an array type then try with explode (or) post as a new question, so that it will be visible to  all members of community to get helped quickly!

Comment: Explode worked, thank you....but if you call explode, it repeats the explode 8 times to account for all trackers

Comment: @dataviews, if trackers array have 8 objects in it then yes.. in case to flatten **`countries`** in trackers then we need to do explode again for **`countries`**

Comment: i updated my code at the bottom of my question if you want to take a look

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior from `spark` as token is two level up from `kpi_values` when we do explode we will get duplicated `token` associated with all the nested fields. http://sqlandhadoop.com/spark-dataframe-explode/ https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView