# Parsing out JSON in Pyspark with unique keys

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm struggling at the moment to work out how to parse out some JSON where the keys are unique so i'm not sure how to do this with the normal pyspark sql functions. Is it possible to do the below without a UDF?

```
{
  "key 1": "value 1",
  "key 2": {
    "key 3": {
      "key 4": {
        "key 5": "value 2",
        "key 6": "value 3"
      },
      "key 7": {
        "key 5": "value 4",
        "key 6": "value 5"
      },
      "key 8": {
        "key 5": "value 6",
        "key 6": "value 7"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to basically turn it into the following table:

```html
| A       | B     | C     | D     | E       | F       |
|---------|-------|-------|-------|---------|---------|
| value 1 | key 2 | key 3 | key 4 | value 2 | value 3 |
| value 1 | key 2 | key 3 | key 7 | value 4 | value 5 |
| value 1 | key 2 | key 3 | key 8 | value 6 | value 7 |
```

If key 4,7 and 8 were the same i'd be able to parse out the below easily however i can't find any context on doing this where the keys for 4,7,8 and so on are unknown and therefore can't be defined in the `get_json_object` function.

Thanks

Comment: Is the JSON standalone or a column in a DataFrame?

Comment: can you list all keys which are known and constant?

Comment: Key 1, 2, 3,5,6 are constant and yes its a string column in a dataframe.

Comment: use from_json and map, check this similar question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658754