# Reading XML in pyspark with same root and row tags

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

this is a part of my XML file with all the necessary depth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Taxonomy>
    <TaxonomyNode>
        <Entity>BUSINESS</Entity>
        <Description>Business News</Description>
        <TaxonomyNode>
            <Entity>COS</Entity>
            <Description>Company News</Description>
            <TaxonomyNode>
                <Entity>ANA</Entity>
                <Description>Analyst Ratings &amp; Commentary</Description>
                <TaxonomyNode>
                    <Entity>ANABUY</Entity>
                    <Description>Analyst Ratings - Buys</Description>
                    <TaxonomyNode>
                        <Entity>ANABEVT</Entity>
                        <Description>Analyst Ratings Events, Announcements - Buys</Description>
                    </TaxonomyNode>
                    <TaxonomyNode>
                        <Entity>BMRANABUY</Entity>
                        <Description>Analyst Ratings - Buys</Description>
                        <TaxonomyNode>
                            <Entity>ANRACC</Entity>
                            <Description>ANR Accumulate</Description>
                        </TaxonomyNode>
                    </TaxonomyNode>
                </TaxonomyNode>
           </TaxonomyNode>
       </TaxonomyNode>
   </TaxonomyNode> 
</Taxonomy>
```

as you can see we have multiple rows with the same name, and reading this with spark with the conventional `spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","TaxonomyNode").load(completeXMLFilePath)` is not working, it is returning me a dataframe looking like this:
[image]

and that has a schema like this:
[image]

I would be thankful if anybody has an idea on how to make this thing work

Comment: Your XML is nested, not flat. It's being read correctly. Do you want to flatten it? If so, why?

Comment: yes that's true, i want to flatten it well to get my data properly

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49672982/6030951